# appending object in dictionary after changing it

Tags: uitextfield, nsmutabledictionary, avaudiorecorder

I am saving a NSMutableArray with different objectsForKeys.
I am having Three of the object be set by input by the user.
I would like to be able to append the new object text with .caf and .txt. So when these are called in the next viewController they can be recognized and used.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)saveAction:(id)sender {

    [self.nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.imageNameTextField resignFirstResponder];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:


                                       @"main.caf",@"pictureAudioKey",
                                       @"audio1.m4a",@"firstAudioKey",
                                       @"audio2.m4a",@"secondAudioKey",
                                       @"audio3.m4a",@"thirdAudioKey",
                                       @"audio4.m4a",@"fourthAudioKey",
                                       @"audio5.m4a",@"fifthAudioKey",
                                       @"audio6.m4a",@"sixthAudioKey",
                                       @"main.jpg",@"photoimagekey",
                                       @"some.txt", @"identity", 
                                       @"imagename.txt",@"numberkey",nil];

 //here is where I change the object values by what the user puts into   the textfield imagename.text 
This works fine especially for the photo since it is recognized as a png without the extension and loaded 
    [dictionary setObject:[[self imageNameTextField]text]
                   forKey:@"photoimagekey"];
//However when you strip the .txt from a text file...or the .caf from an audio //file they are not recognized and not loaded.
    [dictionary setObject:[[self imageNameTextField]text]
                   forKey:@"identity"];
//I tried this
//identity=[identity stringByAppendingFormat:@"txt" But it didn't work

    NSString *audioString = [dictionary objectForKey:@"pictureAudioKey"];
    audioString = [audioString stringByAppendingFormat:@".caf"];
    [dictionary setObject:[[self imageNameTextField]text]
                   forKey:@"pictureAudioKey"];
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
[dictionary setObject:[[self imageNameTextField]text]
               forKey:@"identity"];
```

to:

```
[dictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt", [[self imageNameTextField] text]] 
               forKey:@"identity"];
```